# Can I generate a Google Place ID using place details supplied by a user

Tags: python, api, google-maps

I am trying to build a website where the user can enter a location e.g. a City or town and the website will give them a list of places within a certain radius of that town. I am using the Google Places API.

I cant seem to find any way of letting the user input a location and being able to generate a Place ID with that location that can be used in a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little hard to understand what you want but you might need to get the latitude and longitude of city or town then pass that to places TextSearch as the location. Then for the results obtained from the TextSearch get the ['place_id'] of each and pass them to PlaceDetails to get more information about the place. Again not exactly sure of your problem and there are better ways to do this but here's a brief example of the idea.

```
  url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=' + query + "&" + "location=" + lat + "," + longi + "&key=<your_api_key>"
  resp = requests.get(url)
  data = json.loads(resp.text)
  p = len(data['results'])
  for i in range(p)
      placeId = data['results'][i]['place_id']
      #then pass the placeId to places/details search
```